# Default Dashboard in Salesforce Wave Application

Tags: einstein-analytics

How to choose a default dashboard in the Salesforce Wave application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the App and click on the list icon on the left of the Dashboard label and choose the default dashboard

[image: Screenshot]